# Can we apply universal padding for homepage?

Tags: css, flexbox, frontend, tailwind-css, web-frontend

I'm designing a landing page containing multiple sections each having the same padding from left and right but different background colors. Can I apply this padding to the entire landing page? The issue I'm supposed to face is that the padded area will have the background color of that page not of that section( as it varies for each section). Any feasible solution to this problem would be appreciated. I've attached a screenshot of that page as well.[image]

Comment: Where is your code? How are your sections structured? What exactly have you tried and what didn't work for you?

Comment: I'm applying the corresponding background color and constant padding to each section accordingly. I want to apply padding only once to my entire page. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: On which components do you want to have this universal padding? Can you please include some code?

Comment: What padding? `body {padding 20px}` like this? Please be more precise, I don't know what exactly you are taking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same padding for each section, you can use a common class in each section.

```
.common-class{
   padding: as you want;
}
```

Comment: Dear! I'm asking about how to apply universal padding to entire page instead of each section individually...

Comment: Then you need to be more precise with your question. This totally shows how to add padding

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide your code, I assume your sections are direct children of the body. Then you can set this in your css file:

```
body > section {
   padding: 1rem;
}
```

All sections which are direct children of the `body` will have the padding of `1rem` applied.